# error even after delete project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I delete my project from workspace and Project Explorer of Eclipse but I have error in Error log about File not found. What can I do to don't have an error?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this? What file? What is the exact error message?

Comment: This is something to deal with eclipse restart

Comment: @greg-449 for example this two type: File not found: C:\Users\Sony\workspace\org.eclipse.acceleo.module.php\build.properties and Resource '/org.eclipse.acceleo.module.php1/src/org/eclipse/acceleo/module/php1/main/generateJava.mtl' does not exist.

Comment: @sekhar thanks for your reply,I restart the eclipse but the errors already exist

Comment: @greg-449 might be useful https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/976381/

Comment: I want to delete my files and don't have an error.

Comment: @greg-449 please accept the below as answer.

Comment: @sekhar I didn't ask the question! I only edited it. But in any case an answer that only links to somewhere else is not considered a good answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the eclipse and 
[follow the instructions in this link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/976381/)